# How do I print an outbreak length?

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

I am trying to find the peak day of outbreak (the column in the data frame below labelled as `time`), which works for me by using this code: `out[which.max(out$I), 1]`

I want to find the first day after this one when infections (the column in the data frame below labelled as `I`) level out. So I've tried to do a for loop starting at this max day and run through to the end of the data frame.

The data frame looks like this:

| time | S | I | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 345299.0 | 1.000000 | 0.0000000 |
| 1 | 345298.1 | 1.465194 | 0.4328117 |
| 2 | 345296.8 | 2.146788 | 1.0669638 |
| 3 | 345294.9 | 3.145440 | 1.9961145 |
| 4 | 345292.0 | 4.608629 | 3.3574897 |
| 5 | 345287.9 | 6.752414 | 5.3521414 |

These are my attempts using for loops so far:

```
lengthofoutbreak <- 1000

for (i in out[which.max(out$I), 1]:length(out[out$I]) {
  if (i < lengthofoutbreak) {
    lengthofoutbreak <- out$I
  }
  return(lengthofoutbeak)
}

for (i in out$I) {
  if (out$I < lengthofoutbreak) {
    lengthofoutbreak <- out[out$I, 1]
  }
  return(lengthofoutbeak)
}
```

I just need to see when the outbreak levels off and the approximate day(s) this falls on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends what you mean by "level off". Since the values are continuous (floating-point), `I` will keep decreasing toward zero forever (at least until roundoff error kicks in).

I would suggest something like:

```r
n <- seq(nrow(out))
which(n > which.max(I$out) & diff(I$out) < -0.01)
```

The `diff()` is expected to be negative after the epidemic peak.  In fact, you don't really need the first (`n > which.max()`) clause since `diff(I$out)` will be positive before the epidemic peak ...

This assumes your outbreak trajectory is smooth, not noisy/stochastic.

Comment: Thank you thats really helpful and sorted what I needed to find out